# Is it important to reapply thermal paste to a new (!) CPU after removing it from the socket and installing it on a different motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling

My brand new outside-the-box build doesn't boot, so I want to remove the CPU from it and place it into another motherboard. The paste that was preapplied to the Intel stock heatsink has already melted (on the CPU and the heatsink). How important is it that I remove the melted thermal paste from the heatsink and CPU metal cap and then reapply fresh thermal compound before I install them into the new motherboard? If it's not important, does the answer change if I decide to rotate the heatsink by 90 degrees compared to the original orientation of the heatsink on the first motherboard?

Comment: you apply thermal paste whenever mounting a heatsink on the CPU, however often that happens. clean off the remaining paste, and apply a new dose. the issue isn't that the old paste is bad, but that in the process of seating the heatsink, you are forcing the paste into a seamless layer between the two components, and once its already been done, you can never get it to respread to fill in all the minute gaps between them, causing tiny spots on the cpu die that do not conduct heat into the heatsink at the same rate as the surrounding die-to-sink contact plane.

Comment: Most modern sockets do not allow 90-degree rotation, but no, that would not change my answer. any time you break the contact between the CPU and the heatsink, you clean and reapply paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, if you judge it will not give a good seal, then clean it off and put some more on (I do this as a matter of course) Thermal paste is to help prevent your CPU overheating and potentially failing, you never get a perfect seal metal to metal. Your machine will work without it of course, but best practice is to put some paste on.

Rotation would make no difference.